# How to use loops to improve TikZ/pgfplots-based animation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, animations

I have created a simple animation to illustrate how my code linearizes a function. I created the animation using TikZ and pgfplots. Since I'm quite new to both of those packages, I'm sure I'm not using all of the features. I'd like some feedback on how I can use the looping features to improve this animation.

My current implementation is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xmin = 0.0,
        ymin = 0.0,
        ymax = 4.0,
      ]
      \addplot[ black, samples=200] {1/sqrt(x)};

      \only<2->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.10}]{1/sqrt(x)}; node 1}
      \only<2->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={4.0}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<3>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, 1/sqrt{0.10}) -- (4.0, 1/sqrt{4.0});}

      \only<4->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={1.95}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<4->{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (1.95, 1/sqrt{1.95}) -- (4.0, 1/sqrt{4.0});}
      \only<4>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, 1/sqrt{0.10}) -- (1.95, 1/sqrt{1.95});}

      \only<5->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.925}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<5->{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.925, 1/sqrt{0.925}) -- (1.95, 1/sqrt{1.95});}
      \only<5>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, 1/sqrt{0.10}) -- (0.925, 1/sqrt{0.925});}

      \only<6->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.4125}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<6->{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.4125, 1/sqrt{0.4125}) -- (0.925, 1/sqrt{0.925});}
      \only<6>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, 1/sqrt{0.10}) -- (0.4125, 1/sqrt{0.4125});}

      \only<7>{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.15625}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<7>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.15625, 1/sqrt{0.15625}) -- (0.4125, 1/sqrt{0.4125});}
      \only<7>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, 1/sqrt{0.10}) -- (0.15625, 1/sqrt{0.15625});}

      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. I know how to do this in code to get the actual data, but I'm not sure the magic incantation to do this in TikZ/pgfplots. **How?** A few things I'm interested in:

1. How can I store the function so that I don't have to repeat it every time I want to calculate a point?
2. How can I use a loop to automate this? (There is too much repeated code here.)
3. Can I do this without using beamer?

---

The algorithm I use here is, given a function (1/sqrt(x) in this case) and two points on that curve. Draw a straight line between those two points. If the line is a bad approximation to the curve:

1. Pick a point in the middle of the two original points.
2. Draw lines between the mid-point to the end points.
3. Repeat with each new set of points until the linear approximation is "good enough.

Right now, I don't really care how to determine "good enough", that is more than what is needed for this animation. I really just want to iterate a number of times (5 in this case) as that at least visually does the trick.

Comment: You can store the function using `\tikzset{declare function={myf(\x)=1/sqrt(\x);}}`.

Comment: Another comment: something like `1/sqrt{0.4125}` doesn't work, use `{(1/sqrt(0.4125)}` or `{myf(0.4125)}` instead.

Comment: @marmot you have one parenthesis extra in your comment

Comment: @jfbu Good catch! Thanks! It should be `{1/sqrt(0.4125)}` or `{(1/sqrt(0.4125))}` but not my "compromise" ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, it can be simplified.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{declare function={myf(\x)=1/sqrt(\x);}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xmin = 0,
        ymin = 0.0,
        ymax = 4.0,
      ]
      \addplot[ black, samples=200,domain=0.1:4] {myf(x)};
      \xdef\Lst{(4,{myf(4)}) }
      \only<1>{
      \addplot[thick,dashed, color=red] coordinates {\Lst (0.1,{myf(0.1)}) };
      \addplot[only marks,mark=o,clip=false] coordinates {\Lst (0.1,{myf(0.1)}) };
      }
      \foreach \X in {2,3,4}
      {
      \xdef\Lst{\Lst  ({8*pow(2,-\X)},{myf(8*pow(2,-\X))}) }
      \only<\X>{
      \addplot[thick,dashed, color=red,] coordinates {\Lst (0.1,{myf(0.1)})};
      \addplot[only marks,mark=o,clip=false] coordinates {\Lst (0.1,{myf(0.1)}) };
      }
      }
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Almost same output using @percusse's suggestion and really plotting the function to 4:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{declare function={myf(\x)=1/sqrt(\x);}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xmin = 0,
        ymin = 0.0,
        ymax = 4.0,
      ]
      \addplot[ black, samples=200,domain={1/16}:4] {myf(x)};
      \xdef\Lst{4}
      \only<1>{
      \addplot[thick,dashed, color=red,samples at={\Lst,0.0625}] {myf(x)};
      \addplot[only marks,mark=o,clip=false,samples at={\Lst,0.0625}] {myf(x)};
      }
      \foreach \X [evaluate={\Y=1/16+2*(4-1/16)*pow(2,-\X)}] in {2,3,4}
      {
      \xdef\Lst{\Lst,\Y}
      \only<\X>{
        \addplot[thick,dashed, color=red,samples at={\Lst,0.0625}] {myf(x)};
        \addplot[only marks,mark=o,clip=false,samples at={\Lst,0.0625}] {myf(x)};
      }
      }
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are only using `myf()` then you can use functions with `samples at` key to get rid of the `coordinates`  stuff

Comment: @percusse Yes, in principle. I was trying this first, but then ran into the usual pgfplots expansion problems. Note that I tried several things, and I am not claiming that your suggestion won't work. Yet my first attempt did not.  What I noticed, however, is that `\pause` really causes issues, but it is not needed here either.

Comment: what I mean is you can simply recreate an array at each pause (via `only`) and pass it to the same line of addplot to the `samples at` key

Comment: @percusse Thanks!!! I added your suggestion. If you want me to remove it, please let me know.

Comment: While this generates the appropriate output, I don't fully understand the line ` \foreach \X [evaluate={\Y=8*pow(2,-\X)}] in {2,3,4}` I presume that this is intending to calculate the intermediate points. Also why use the `min` function as part of `myf`?

Comment: @jlconlin Yes, it does. The length of the interval is 4, and you want to put the extra points at 4/2, 4/4, 4/8. As I am using `\X` in only, this expression yields precisely the desired values. (Of course, `\X` should not be confused with a horizontal coordinate, it is just a loop variable.) And I am using `min` since otherwise I get all the nasty complaints that some value has been dropped. The cleaner way to go it to restrict the domain, as I have done in the first example. If you really want to plot all the way to 4, the lower bound needs to become `{1/16}` instead of `0.1`.)

Comment: Oh, I see where you are coming from now. Note that I don’t want it at 4/2, 4/4, etc. The first two points are at 4 and 0.1. The third point is  between them; x=(4-0.1)/2. Each subsequent point is dependent on the midpoint calculated in the previous step. Granted, it will look nearly identical to presented solution. I just ask because it will be a more general answer Andy I’m trying to learn this stuff. Thank!

Comment: @jlconlin Weird, I didn't see your message in my inbox, so sorry for the delay. I added the `0.1` shift, as you suggest, even though I'd think that `1/16` may be more appropriate. (Note that I will be really offline for a while now.)

Comment: @jlconlin I changed my mind and used 1/16 instead.

Answer (score 3):

After playing a bit with braces and parentheses I modified you mwe into this

(but I do know this does not answer the OP about doing a loop: it only shows how to get the original MWE compile without errors)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xmin = 0.0,
        ymin = 0.0,
        ymax = 4.0,
      ]
      \addplot[ black, samples=200] {1/sqrt(x)};

      \only<2->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.10}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<2->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={4.0}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<3>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, {1/sqrt(0.10)}) -- (4.0, {1/sqrt(4.0)});}

      \only<4->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={1.95}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<4->{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (1.95, {1/sqrt(1.95)}) -- (4.0, {1/sqrt(4.0)});}
      \only<4>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, {1/sqrt(0.10)}) -- (1.95, {1/sqrt(1.95)});}

      \only<5->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.925}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<5->{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.925, {1/sqrt(0.925)}) -- (1.95, {1/sqrt(1.95)});}
      \only<5>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, {1/sqrt(0.10)}) -- (0.925, {1/sqrt(0.925)});}

      \only<6->{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.4125}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<6->{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.4125, {1/sqrt(0.4125)}) -- (0.925, {1/sqrt(0.925)});}
      \only<6>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, {1/sqrt(0.10)}) -- (0.4125, {1/sqrt(0.4125)});}

      \only<7>{\addplot[only marks, color=black,fill=white,samples at={0.15625}]{1/sqrt(x)};}
      \only<7>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.15625, {1/sqrt(0.15625)}) -- (0.4125, {1/sqrt(0.4125)});}
      \only<7>{\draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (0.10, {1/sqrt(0.10)}) -- (0.15625, {1/sqrt(0.15625)});}

      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And it works. (compiling in article class only the tikz code is much much faster than with beamer, I don't know why).

**edit** but there are dozens of warnings in log from the `1/sqrt(0)` overflows, thanks @marmot for drawing my attention to that. Using

```
\addplot[ black, samples=200, domain=0.1:4] {1/sqrt(x)};
```

as in @marmot's answer fixes that **and significantly speeds up processing!**

Here is with commenting out `frame`, adding `\def\only<#1>#2{#2}` and using article class:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. +1. But I guess you will still get complaints that some coordinates have been dropped. (That's the reason why I restricted the domain in my answer.)

Comment: @marmot you are absolutely right. I had been using `xmin = 0.01` when the MWE was not compiling, then when it started compiling I went back to `= 0.0` and did not pay attention to the numerous warnings in log ...

Comment: @marmot I edited my answer, because my xmin business is crap and your domain restriction also improves noticeably the build time.