# PGF math broken in \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfmath

Following my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428316/how-to-use-loops-to-improve-tikz-pgfplots-based-animation/428326#428326) I've tried to make my example a bit more general as well as complex. (Note: I don't want this more complex, but this is what I want my graphics to do.)

When I have the following, I get the error:

```
NOTE: coordinate (2Y1.2575e-1],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump).
NOTE: coordinate (2Y7.55e-2],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump).
NOTE: coordinate (2Y2.525e-2],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unboundd (in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump).
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Xmid
                 , XS{\Xmid }
l.38     \end{axis}

?
```

The offending part is a `\foreach` statement; If I comment out the `\foreach` as shown below, everything compiles fine. Unfortunately, I need the `\foreach` statement to complete my graphics.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \tikzset{declare function={XS(\x)=1/sqrt(\x);}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xmin = -0.5,
        ymin = 0.0,
        ymax = 5.0,
      ]
      \addplot[ black, samples=200] {XS(x)};

      \xdef\Xmin{0.1}
      \xdef\Xmax{4.0}

      \pgfmathsetmacro\startIndex{3}
      % \foreach \n in {0,...,4}{
      %   \pgfmathsetmacro{\onlyIndex}{int(\n+\startIndex)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmid}{(\Xmax-\Xmin)/2}

        % \only<\onlyIndex->{
        \only<3->{
          \addplot[only marks, color=black, fill=white, samples at={\Xmid}]{XS(x)};
          \draw[thick, dashed, color=red] (\Xmid, XS{\Xmid}) -- (\Xmax, XS{\Xmax});
        }

        \xdef\Xmax{\Xmid}
      % }

      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**What is wrong with my `\foreach` loop that causes problems with `\Xmid`?**

I'm trying to add points on the curve between the two left-most points and draw a line between them. I'm trying to create an animation illustrating how to create a linear approximation to a curve. The two left-most points changes (of course) at each iteration. This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428316/how-to-use-loops-to-improve-tikz-pgfplots-based-animation/428326#428326).

Comment: Could it just be the usual `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` vs. `\pgfmathsetmacro` thingy?

Comment: @marmot I wasn't aware of `\pgftruncatemacro`, but I tried it where in both places and it does't fix it.

Comment: @marmot No, he has `int(..)` which does the same thing.

Comment: `\startIndex{3}` is not used because when it is used (to set `\onlyIndex`), then things stop working.

Comment: foreach inside the axis is scoped and does not survive until pgfplots gather everything. So instead you need to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4}{...}` and instead of `\n` use `#1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were a few issues.

1. Better restrict the plot to a domain to switch off the warnings.
2. Use `{XS(\Xmid)}` instead of `XS{\Xmid}`. `XS` is a function that you have declared, and the correct syntax for evaluating a function uses ordinary brackets. The curly brackets around the result make Ti*k*Z evaluate the thing.
3. If you want an integer index, use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. (This was not really an issue here.)
4. I added `\xdef\Xmid{\Xmid}` *before* the loop such that it is global and known inside the loop.

I also added a mark at `\Xmax`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \tikzset{declare function={XS(\x)=1/sqrt(\x);}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        xmin = -0.5,
        ymin = 0.0,
        ymax = 5.0,
      ]
      \addplot[ black, samples=200,domain={1/25}:5] {XS(x)};

      \xdef\Xmin{0.04}
      \xdef\Xmax{4.0}

      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\startIndex{3}
      \only<\startIndex->{
      \addplot[only marks, color=black, fill=white, samples at={\Xmax},
          domain={1/25}:5,clip=false]{XS(x)};
      }
      \foreach \n in {0,...,6}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\onlyIndex}{int(\n+\startIndex)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmid}{\Xmin+(\Xmax-\Xmin)/2}
        \xdef\Xmid{\Xmid}
         \only<\onlyIndex->{
          \addplot[only marks, color=black, fill=white, samples at={\Xmid},
          domain={1/25}:5,clip=false]{XS(x)};
          \addplot[thick, dashed, color=red, samples at={\Xmid,\Xmax}]{XS(x)};
       }
        \xdef\Xmax{\Xmid}
       }

      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The loop was the whole point of the question, so odd thing to not care about. I see it works now though, so +1.

Comment: Okay so adding the `\typeout{\onlyIndex,\Xmid}
        \xdef\Xmid{\Xmid}`
did the trick. What does it do and why is it needed?

Comment: I've restricted my domain by added `xmax=10.0`, but that didn't change any of the warnings. I suspect you mean to restrict it in some other manner that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @jlconlin I'll remove the `\typeout`, this was only for me to understand what's going on, and I left it by mistake. The issues were what I mentioned above + the thing I mentioned in my reply to Torbjørn.  And no, `xmax` does not restrict the lower end of the interval, which is where the warnings come from. If you tell me what you want to achieve, I could try to rewrite my answer in such a way that that works.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `(\Xmid, {XS(\Xmid)})` (with braces) `(\Xmid, XS{\Xmid})`? I don't quite understand when to use braces and when not to. BTW, restricting the domain as you've shown helps a lot.

Comment: @jlconlin I have rewritten my answer to include this and want to say sorry for my statement about `\Xmax`. I think now to understand its purpose. (However, I think that the new coordinate should be `\Xmin+(\Xmax-\Xmin)/2` instead of `(\Xmax-\Xmin)/2` since otherwise the coordinates become smaller than `\Xmin`. I also adjusted the range and `xmin` in such a way that the plot really reaches the maximal value `ymax=5`.